# How can I create a development environment that closely mimics a production environment?

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, vps, deployment, development

I want an Nginx reverse proxy server for load balancing that directs clients to one of two node.js web application servers. I plan to eventually deploy this project on a linux operating system probably on a vps.

I'm currently using windows 7 32 bit for development. As far as I can tell, apparently nginx does not support load balancing on windows. How can I use windows 7 32 bit to mimic a production environment, which presumably would be on a linux operating system? E.g. virtual machine? Docker?

Comment: Windows 7 is end of life since January 2020 so I would upgrade it to w10 in the first place... If you want to "closely mimics" you must run on the same OS, so either a Linux VM or another vps that you use just for testing

Comment: Not just Windows 10 you also should get a modern computer. Something you can run several virtual machines on, which is the way you would create such environments locally. The ancient computer you are using now is not up to the task.